# What is the meaning of "get held under the water"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "You pull in the barrel and then you eat it and you just go spinning
>   and get held under water forever"

I read it but I didn't really get it. I mean does it means that he drowns? Please help me with this one.

Comment: If he is held under the water long enough, of course, he will drown. But often a kid who is mean or just horsing around will hold someone under water relatively briefly, until they start thrashing round to escape. Doing so can lead to coughing and gasping (and can be quite unpleasant) but is very far from life-threatening.

Comment: the sentence exactly was "You pull in the barrel and then you eat it and you just go spinning and get held under water forever" 
It is about surfing . @SvenYargs

Comment: That sentence is almost certainly an exaggeration by someone who has experienced the series of things described in the sentence and has lived to tell the tale. The author just means "held under water [presumably by a collapsed wave] for a long but not fatal or even seriously injurious period of time."

Comment: @SvenYargs thnks for helping, this article am writing is really bothering .. thanks ^_^

Comment: Jessica, you need to put that sentence in your question. The question means nothing without that context.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock well I guess I got the right answer but thanks anyway ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You pull in the barrel

When a wave crashes over itself, it can form a tube of water surrounding air.  That's called a barrel, and surfers like to ride their boards on the inside of the barrel.  You can watch it [here](https://youtu.be/2h9i3vz1csw).

> and then you eat it

You fall off the board, also calling "wiping out."

> and you just go spinning

Once you're in the water, you'll spin as the wave tucks under.

> and get held under water forever

You're in the water, no longer gliding on the surface on your board, and the wave crashes over on you, pushing you under.  It will seem like forever until you can swim up to get to air.

Comment: sorry to bother you again .. but what does across the board mean in surfing too? it is sth about the marks or results I guess

Comment: Do you have a sentence in mind?  "Across the board" is an idiom meaning to affect everything or everyone.  Literally, it could just means sideways on a surfboard.  Let me have some context.

Comment: Multiple World Champ Gary Hunt -and winner of the last round in Texas - is looking on- form here.  
And with 8.5’s across the board, he’s taken an early lead.
@deadrat

Comment: This is about cliff diving, not surfing.  There are five judges for each dive, and each judge awards a score from 0-10.  Go here: http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2yp7z4 at 2:10.  "8.5's across the board" means that every judge gave Hunt a score of 8.5 on one of his dives.

Comment: sorry I meant cliff diving, I just got confused cuz am writing about several free sports @deadrat

Comment: just one more question, am not really interested in those sports so I dont know much, Multiple Champ means that he won several times or what? @deadrat

Comment: Yes, several times is right.  In fact, 2010, 2011, and 2012.

Comment: thanks alot .. am not ganna bother you any more so thank you very much ^_^

Comment: You're welcome.  You're not bothering me: vivo ut serviam.  In any case, you have 10 questions left in this half.  Hey, that was a sports joke!  (Make "a lot" two words.  "Gonna" is the way to spell the slang form of "going to.")

Comment: yea I know those stuff but I type quick so I might make mistakes
English is the topic of my work and study, and am good in sports like football and tennis and I have a lot of info about horses, but freesports are new topic for me and am suffering cuz of them